# Websockets only webapplication?

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I was recently introduced to websockets and I was thinking whether or not it could be possible or good idea to create webapplication only by using websockets.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. What would said web application's purpose be for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "only websockets"?  You'd have to supply at least an HTML page using "normal" HTTP if you wanted people to look at it using a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model that works pretty well is that you use HTTP to get the static content (HTML, JavaScript, CSS, possibly images) of your web app to the browser and leverage websockets for everything that's dynamic.
The beauty of this is that you can take advantage of caching for all the static resources.

With other words, you can completely eliminate the dynamically generated markup on the server-side (a'la JSP, PHP, and alike).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do that.

Your only caveat is that your webapplication is the limited to browser which support the websockets protocol. That is why lots of folks chooses a server/client library like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to have fallbacks to other communication-layers, like XHR.